# SQL Server trigger update column from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am trying to create a fairly simple SQL Server trigger, hope someone can help.

I have a table with structure like this:

Table #1:

```
CREATE TABLE `teg_priority` (
    `UCIDN` BIGINT(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `CIDN` BIGINT(50) NOT NULL,
    `CustomerName` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    `NGM` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Service_Manager` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `CBS` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `Tag` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`CIDN`)
)
```

and another table (table #2):

```
CREATE TABLE `custalign` (
    `UCIDN` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `CIDN` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `CustomerName` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`CIDN`)
)
```

I am trying to set up a trigger where every time a new record is inserted into the first table that the following query will be run as a trigger to update field UCIDN in table 1

```
update teg_priority
set teg_priority.UCIDN = (select UCIDN from custalign 
where teg_priority.CIDN = custalign.CIDN)
```

The above query works i just don't know how to write it as a trigger statement.

Please help.

Comment: Are you saying you don't know how to create a trigger? If so, start with this page: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Comment: This question is **tagged** with `sql-server` (as in **Microsoft SQL Server**) - but the backticks around the column names of the tables seem to hint at **MySQL** instead - please make sure you have the **right** tags!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try out this..hope this will helps you

**For MySQL**

```
CREATE TRIGGER teg_priorityTrigger AFTER INSERT ON teg_priority
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    UPDATE inserted
    set inserted.UCIDN = (select UCIDN from custalign 
    where inserted.CIDN = custalign.CIDN)
END
```

**For SQL Server**

```
CREATE TRIGGER teg_priorityTrigger ON dbo.teg_priority AFTER INSERT
    AS
      UPDATE inserted
      set inserted.UCIDN = (select UCIDN from custalign 
      where inserted.CIDN = custalign.CIDN)
```

hope this will helps you...

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Teg_priority_after_insert 
ON dbo.teg_priority AFTER INSERT
AS

UPDATE inserted
set inserted.UCIDN = (select UCIDN from custalign 
where inserted.CIDN = custalign.CIDN)
```

That's your answer.  You might consider a change in approach; assuming it doesn't require a total re-work of your process-flow.  I can't really suggest more without knowing what you're ultimately trying to accomplish.

In SQL Server triggers, there is an `inserted` and a `deleted` table automatically-generated to which you may refer. Each respectively contains the new and old records as a result of whatever statement `AFTER [INSERT],[UPDATE],[DELETE]`.  The `inserted` table is accessible to AFTER INSERT and UPDATE triggers, while the `deleted` table is accessible to AFTER UPDATE and DELETE triggers.

That might be more than you wanted to know, but I thought you'd benefit from a brief explanation of where the `inserted` table came from in my code.

[Insert all the usual caveats about trying not to use triggers wherever possible here.]

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. The trigger is not creating , it complains about the syntax ? I am not using ms sql, it is mysql

Comment: I see... when I answered, the tag in the question had "sql-server-triggers" in it.  You should be able to google "MySQL AFTER INSERT trigger", skim the syntax, re-tool my answer to work with MySQL's syntax.